# Capturing network flow in realtime

Tags: network-programming, pcap

I've a machine learning model that analyses network flow data for botnet traffic generated from pcap files using splitpcap ( https://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap ). This tool is obviously after the fact. Is there any means or tooling to capture similar network flow data as splitpcap but in realtime, which could be then fed into a machine learning model.

I've investigated hooking into the Linux kernel or tapping packets off, and then somehow tracking and collecting network flow data. But, seems to overly complex and long-winded.